# How to change the working directory for build/debug in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, ide, gdb

I'm trying to get accustomed to using Emacs for building and debugging, although I'm having some difficulties. My biggest problem right now is that I need to be in (e.g. have a file open in) the root directory to `make -k` my applications and I need to be in the binaries directory to run `gdb MyApp`.

Is it futile to try to get Ctrl+Shift+B to `make -k -C <my_hard_coded_dir>` and some type of ditto with F5 running `gdb <MyApp>` from my bin directory? Never mind if the shift key is to much of a hassle for Emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify what M-x make uses for compilation, you specify the compile-command variable.

```
(setq compile-command "make -c /path/to/makefile")
```

For your GDB stuff, the variable is gud-gdb-command-name, so

```
(setq gud-gdb-command-name "gdb --anotate=3 -cd /path/to/exec")
```

Comment: The option is `-C` and not `-c`. See here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary

Answer (score 2):

for compiling i use this spippet in my .emacs

```
(global-set-key [f2]   'compile)
(global-set-key [f3]   'next-error)
(setq compile-command "u: & cd \\gbceinspielen\\trunk\\src\\compile & make -k ")
```

the command "gdb" starts the debugger, but i do not know, wether there is an equivalent to compile-command.

Comment: And to get Ctrl-Shift-B, substitute (kbd "C-S-b") for [f2].

Comment: One plus for pointing out starters for make, but had to do make -C <mydir> -k, since cd didn't work (Linux problem?). No luck with finding gdb variables though. Is there some type of list for these variables and what they do?

Comment: okay, sorry for gdb, (i thought i should have, but i did not know, because i do not use it)

finding things: M-x apropos

Comment: I've searched apropos in vain. Btw: (kbd "C-S-b") does not work for me (tries to move the cursor, yields "already at beginning of buffer", etc), but it's not really important.

Comment: If you are using Emacs on the console, or in xterm or similar, Control-Shift-letter is not differentiated from Control-letter, and Control-b is backward-char. You need to use a windowing system for that kind of combinations to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personaly use EDE to keep compilation settings for concrete projects, and create compile command on the fly.  You can see how it works in [my cedet config](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/a67483764df95690a4a7dd53af523e600fdbefa5/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el), starting with line 100